# WPF User Tracking: Application Insight vs. HockeyApp or something else?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp, user-tracking

I want to track some basic information from my WPF application:

- which version do the users use
- how long do they use the application
- errors and how often some features are used

... all together with an unique user-id to distinguish the users in the data later.

There is Microsoft's Application Insight, which was originally developed for ASP.NET websites - but which could also be used in WPF applications.
But there newer sources say, HockeyApp is better and should be used, since Application Insight is deprecated. 
There seems also be an integration between HockeyApp an AI.

My question is: What is best practice and most promising solution for user tracking in WPF applications in 2018? Application Insight, HockeyApp or are there other third-party solutions?

Answer (score 1):

> What is best practice and most promising solution for user tracking in WPF applications in 2018?

I belive you are looking for the [Windows Desktop Application Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/windows-desktop-application-program). It provides a convenient, one-stop portal to view desktop application analytics or access the data via an API. You can sign up for free.

**Introducing the Windows Desktop Program for Desktop Application Analytics:** https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/01/23/introducing-windows-desktop-program-desktop-application-analytics/#sFhhI59SKdhTlCW6.97

Comment: Never heard of this so far. Will have a look at it.

Comment: Looks interesting. But one question: How do the data go to MS? Where does the user approve his ok to send telemetry for my app to Microsoft? They just say, the prove that's your application by checking the signing certificate - but not, what happens after that, after an application is signed and installed on 100 user machines.